# ahk_id will be the same over different machines? (AutoHotKey script)

Tags: autohotkey

Does filtering/matching by a specific `ahk_id` will work only on the machine where I got the `ahk_id` from? Or it's "global" and will work across different machines?

Also, how does the `ahk_id` is generated?

Thanks

Comment: This number is a window handle assigned by OS, it changes each time that app runs.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Do you want to write it as an answer or I'll do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Each window has a **unique ID**, also known as a **HWND** (short for **handle to window**). This ID can be used to identify the window even if its title changes.
- The ID of a window is typically retrieved via WinExist() or WinGet and is a specific **arbitrary** number. **It changes each time a program runs.**
- **ahk_id** is used to identify a window based off the windows unique ID (HWND).

https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_id